# Security Incident with Ubuntu Studio 19.10 and .vbs file?

Tags: thunderbird

Today I got an email in Thunderbird. Someone had hacked into my business colleague's PC. It looked real. It had a .vbs attachment that was password protected in a google drive doc. I went there and downloaded the .vbs file; I couldn't open it in Linux. I was suspicious and emailed back and my colleague told me that her pc was hacked. So I deleted the email and the downloaded file.

Could I have got into any trouble for this on Ubuntu? I mean, could I have loaded malware onto my computer? Or have I fallen for any kind of browser hijack? [no signs of either].